# Get individual dask dataframe partition status

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I like to run an asynchronous dask dataframe computation with *dd.persist()* and then been able to track an individual partition status. The goal is to get access to partial results in a non-blocking way.

Here the desired pseudo code:

```
dd = dd.persist()
if dd.partitions[0].__dask_status__ == 'finished':
    # Partial non-blocking result access
    df = dd.partitions[0].compute()
```

Using dask futures works well, but submitting many individual partitions is very slow compared to a single *dd.persist()* and having one future per partition breaks the dashboard "groups" tab by showing too many blocks.

```
futures = list(map(client.compute, dd.partitions))
```

[Broken dask dashboard "groups" tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRh3F.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you probably want is `distributed.futures_of`, which lists the running futures of a collection. You can either examine this list yourself, looking at the status of the futures, or use with `distributed.as_completed` and a for-loop to process the partitions as they become available. The keys of the futures are like `(collection-name, partition-index)`, so you know which partition each belongs to.

The reason `dd.partitions[i]` (or looping over these with `list`) doesn't work, is that this creates a new graph for each partition, and so you end up submitting much more to the scheduler than the single call to `.persist()`.